# How do I make ssh fail rather than prompt for a password if the public-key authentication fails?

Tags: ssh, authentication, public-key

I've got a script that SSHes several servers using public key authentication. One of the servers has stopped letting the script log in due to a configuration issue, which means that the script gets stuck with a "Password:" prompt, which it obviously cannot answer, so it doesn't even try the rest of the servers in the list.

Is there a way to tell the ssh client not to prompt for a password if key authentication fails, but instead to just report an error connecting and let my script carry on?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

For OpenSSH there is BatchMode, which in addition to disabling password prompting, should disable querying for passphrase(s) for keys.

> BatchMode
>
> > If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled.
> >     This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no
> >     user is present to supply the password.  The argument must be
> >     “yes” or “no”.  The default is “no”.

Sample usage:

```
ssh -oBatchMode=yes -l <user> <host> <dostuff>
```

Comment: This disabled public key authentication for me.  I was specifying as ssh user@host -C somecommand, however.  What eneded up working for me is just `ssh user@host -oPreferredAuthentications=publickey -C 'echo success'`

Answer (score 47):

- To disable password authentication for the current ssh connection attempt, pass this option on the command line:

  ```
  -o PasswordAuthentication=no
  ```
- To disable password authentication for all future connections to any host add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

  ```
  PasswordAuthentication no
  ```
- To disable it for just some hosts, add the following to ~/.ssh/config:

  ```
  Host host1 host2 host3...
      PasswordAuthentication no
  ```

The options above apply to **out-going** ssh connections, i.e. where you're trying to connect to a remote ssh server.

To disable password authentication on an ssh server (i.e. applies to all **incoming** ssh connections), add `PasswordAuthentication no` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart `sshd`.

Comment: if you don't want to disable password auth for all ssh client connections, you can also specify options on the command line.  add '-oPasswordAuthentication=no' to your ssh command.

Comment: This does not prevent the password prompt. OP's script will still hang.

Comment: @JoshuaSwink: Yes it does. I just tried it (on the command line as `-oPasswordAuthentication=no`. You get an error like `Permission denied (publickey,password).` and it exits immediately.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Curious to know why not, it seems like it should work. (-oBatchMode=yes and -oNumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 both work for me so YMMV)

Answer (score 12):

If you are using dropbear, just add the "`-s`" option to disable password authentication.

Comment: +1 for not assuming the client is openssh :-)

Answer (score 9):

On the command line (or `~/.ssh/config`) you can set `PreferredAuthentications`.

```
PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```

Comment: I think that, on the command line, you need to wrap the option in quotes and then pass it to the -o option.

Comment: @CraigWalker You can also pass it as is, i.e. `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey`

Comment: @CraigWalker You need quotes if you wish to use spaces to separate the option and the value e.g. `ssh "-oPreferredAuthentications publickey"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample sftp bash script snippet. I am using "-o BatchMode=Yes" to disable the password prompt in case of failure. And check the frp return code to check if the ftp connection failed.

```
sftp -o "IdentityFile=<YOUR_IDENTTIY_FILE>"  -o "BatchMode=Yes" userName@ftpserver.com <<EOF

cd /$remotepath
mget *.csv $localpath/download

quit
EOF
exit_code=$?
if [[ $exit_code != 0 ]]; then
   echo "sftp error, failed to connect to ftp server" >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that BatchMode set to yes is what disables the interactive auth (i.e. password prompt).